# Rails 4 API: Creating a nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-4, has-one-through

I have 3 models:

```
class Repositioning < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :repo_mood
    has_one :mood, through: :repo_mood
end

class Mood < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :repo_moods
    has_many :repositionings, through: :repo_moods
end

class RepoMood < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :repositioning
    belongs_to :mood
end
```

But I only have a `Repositionings` controller.  In my app, the user can add a `mood` to the `repositioning` and the data is sent to my API as:

```
repositioning: { mood: mood_id }
```

Is there a railsy way of generating the necessary `repo_mood` entry:

```
RepoMood.create(repositioning_id: repositioning.id, mood_id: mood_id)
```

without manually calling it?  I'm thinking like nested forms in a Rails view.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon, it's for building nested model forms. Even if you don't use it, read through the documentation because it will go over a lot of ins and outs of dealing with nested models. It really helped me wrap my head around this stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for) to do this.

It'll allow you to create related models simply by passing the proper attributes to your API endpoint.